# Python MySQL and context managers: __exit__ Attribute error

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, contextmanager

Using Python 2.7.9, I'm trying to factor out the opening and closing of mysql connections and cursors

The code is

```
class MySQLCursor:
    def __init__(self, commit=False):
        self.commit = commit

    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=_MYMYSQLHOST,
                                    user=_MYMYSQLUSER,
                                    passwd=_MYMYSQLPASSWD,
                                    db=_MYMYSQLDB)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if self.commit:
            self.conn.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
        self.conn.close()
        return
```

using it as

```
with MySQLCursor as cursor:
    cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print "server version:", row[0]
```

I get the error message

```
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Is this a mysql problem or a context manager problem?

Comment: try `with MySQLCursor() as cursor`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do `with MySQLCursor() as cursor:` - The With statements needs instances of classes that have the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, not the classes themselves.